# emberjs post variables in RESTadapter

Tags: ember.js

Consider the following code:

```
App.ListingAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: document.location.origin + '/rest'
});
```

How would I go about sending parameters in the ajax request?  if I wanted to say pass something like ?var1=a&var2=b  etc? or simply post vars in the request?

Comment: You would like to pass the parameters on each request?

Comment: Correct, for example... I might want to pass a user_id and/or limit the number or records being returned.  For example:  user_id=abd93da&limit=50

Comment: You can pass user_id as header but why would you like to pass some limit on each ajax request? You probably want to pass these parameters only on some route, I am right?

Comment: You can add metadata with requests http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/models/handling-metadata/, I'm not sure why you'd want the same for all request though.

Comment: Limits are important for example if you have a 'master' user account, and you have several thousand records in the db.  I want to try and pass search params so I'm only loading records from a specific user, time frame etc. Or instead of loading 10,000 records, I'm only loading 100 at a time.  Metadata pertains to data on the client side no? After it has come in?